# Split delimited single value character vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a user provided String like `"Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri"`. Please note that this value is user provided input. User may provide something like `"Mon,Tue,Wed"` and so on.

I want to get this as vector which will be used for plotting and for further analytics.

Since the value provided by user is a single comma delimited value, we need to separate the value in to individual values and then construct vector.

Is there any way to construct vector directly.

i.e I should get a vector from "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri". As expected, below code returns a single value vector.

```
> weekdays <- c(days)

> print(weekdays)
[1] "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri"
```

But I need something like below

```
> days <- c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri")
> print(days)
[1] "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri"
```

Note that I am not reading a CSV file. I am just trying to read a user provided single CSV row as vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` for that:

```
wkdays <- "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri"
unlist(strsplit(wkdays, ","))
```

this gives:

> ```
> > unlist(strsplit(wkdays, ","))
> [1] "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri"
> ```

---

An alternative is to use `scan`:

```
scan(text = wkdays, sep = ",", what = character())
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: It returns a list in case wkdays is a vector of length>1 and several splits are needed. Here wkdays is a vector of length 1 so you would extract the first element of the list with `strsplit(wkdays, ",")[[1]]`.

Comment: @antoine-sac true, added `unlist`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `stringr::str_split_1` (which is loaded automatically when using `tidyverse`):

```
library(stringr)
str_split_1("foo,bar", ",")
[1] "foo" "bar"
```

To me, this feels a bit more crisp compared to the accepted solution. See https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/12/stringr-1-5-0/#splitting for details