# Loop through a comma separated text and fix value with variables or get a first column, second column etc. to define variables with a value

Tags: r

Want to loop through a comma separated text file.
For ex:

```
mytext <- 3,24,25,276,2,87678,20-07-2022,1,5
```

From this mytext I would like to loop through like below :

```
for (i in 1:length(mytext)) {
  print(mytext[[i]])
}
```

I need to display like

```
3
24
25
276
2
87678
20-07.2021
1
5
```

Actually I need to set every value as an individual variable, like :

```
variable1:3
variable2:24
variable3:25
variable4:276
variable5:2
variable6:87678
variable7:20-07.2021
variable8:1
variable9:5
```

(my project is retrieve data from text file and then having database validations in R before entering records to database.)

Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strsplit(mytext,",")`.

Comment: Use `message` or `writeLines` instead of `print`. You (almost) never want to or need to call `print` explicitly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split delimited single value character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102311/split-delimited-single-value-character-vector)

Comment: sorry my question was not correct before. Now I have corrected it. Please have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Split your string:

```
strsplit(mytext, ",")[[1]]
```