# How to get an element from a text string in R

Tags: r, string

```
> my_data <- "08,23,02.06.2022,5,7,THISPRODUCT,09.02.2022,yes,89,25"
> lengths(gregexpr(",", my_data))+1
[1] 10
```

I need to get each element individually. I tried with
print(gregexpr(",", my_data))[[1]][1]

```
> print(gregexpr(",", my_data))[[1]][1]
[[1]]
[1]  3  6 17 19 21 33 44 48 51
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"index.type")
[1] "chars"
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

[1] 3
```

but my_data has the first element "08" but it displays 3.. anyone give me correct syntax to display every element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split delimited single value character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102311/split-delimited-single-value-character-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

strings <- "08,23,02.06.2022,5,7,THISPRODUCT,09.02.2022,yes,89,25" %>% 
  str_split(pattern = ",") %>% 
  unlist()

strings[1]
#> [1] "08"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. so looks like we need to use tidyverse library to get individual element of a string. It resolved my issue : )

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `scan`

```
> scan(text = my_data, what = "",sep = ",",quiet = TRUE)
 [1] "08"          "23"          "02.06.2022"  "5"           "7"
 [6] "THISPRODUCT" "09.02.2022"  "yes"         "89"          "25"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply`:

```
lapply(strsplit(my_data, ","), `[`)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "08"          "23"          "02.06.2022"  "5"           "7"           "THISPRODUCT" "09.02.2022"  "yes"        
 [9] "89"          "25"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
unlist(strsplit(my_data, split = ","))
```